# Why UIDatePicker is not showing the time and days in .inline style in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, uidatepickermodetime, swiftui-datepicker

Hi I have a `UIDatePicker` with `inline` style and `dateAndTime` mode as InputView to a UITextField, and when datePicker appears its not showing the days and the time. Please refer the image1(when it appears) and image2(when tap on time).

[image: When datePicker appears]

[image: When tap on the time]

This is my code

```
func createDatePicker(startDate: Date) {
   let toolbar = UIToolbar()
   toolbar.sizeToFit()
            
   let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
   let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
   let cancelBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: nil, action: #selector(cancelPressed))
   toolbar.setItems([cancelBtn, space, doneBtn], animated: true)
            
   datePicker.locale = .current
   datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
   datePicker.minimumDate = startDate
   if #available(iOS 14, *) {
      datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
      datePicker.sizeToFit()
   } else {
                 
   }            
   self.starDateTimeTF.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
   self.starDateTimeTF.inputView = datePicker
}
```

And how I'm expecting is like this,
[image]

Please help.